# Bind IIS wildcard subdomain

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7.5, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I need to add a "Site Mapping" on IIS 7.5 to accept domains that meet some wildcard, for example:
I need some web site to be mapped to the subdomain:

*.aaa.bbbb.com

That means: anything.aaa.bbbb.com and so.

Comment: Server configuration questions are better suited for http://serverfault.com

Comment: why not bind the site to an IP address and then bind all those DNS entries to that set of IP addresses.  Sound easier than trying to do some crazy host header wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not possible to do that. You need to resolve the wildcard issue with DNS settings.

There is a request for this feature on Microsoft Connect. Vote for it [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/WindowsServerFeedback/feedback/details/722874/wildcard-subdomain-hostheader-support-in-iis-7-5) :)

Comment: Thanx, but aren't there any non-Microsoft solution!